# SQL Command Execute Successfully but data is not inserted in WPF Form

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am facing a problem in inserting data in WPF form. There is not error in code , query runs successfully however when i Check my Database there is no data. Following is the code:

```
 bool insert()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            string query = "Insert into checkouts(cnic,medicine,next_trip) VALUES('@c','@m','@n')";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", cnic_box.Text.Replace("-",""));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", med_box.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n",Convert.ToDateTime(date_box.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Connection.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What database? Do you have explicit transactions there?

Comment: How do you know if it executed successfuly? int count=command.ExecuteNonQuery(); to find out how many rows are inserted.

Comment: @DheerajRoy because there is no syntax error and when I paste the query in SQL Server it runs successfully.

Comment: No syntax error doesnt mean successful execution of query, and way of execution in c# and sqlserver studio is different. You should use count to get count of inserted rows. That would give you confirmation.

Comment: @DheerajRoy I have now used integer variable to check how many rows it returns and it is returning 1 which means query is executing.

Comment: what you have assigned in Connection object? Is servernames, database names are correct?

Comment: @DheerajRoy yes they are connect and connection is also opening successfully.

Comment: VALUES('@c','@m','@n')... instead it should be VALUES(@c,@m,@n)

Comment: Problem still persists @DheerajRoy

Comment: cnic_box.Text.Replace("-","")  instead cnic_box.Text.Replace("-","").toString()   and med_box.Text.ToString(). Also check if these variables  dont have null values.

Comment: Add something in catch to print, if it is throwing any unexpected exceptions

Comment: Are you using a MDF file? It may be getting overwritten in your compile/execute cycle.... Run a `Select` right after your `Insert` command to verify properly that the data is there.

Comment: @Jstreet yes I am using MDF File.

Comment: What happens if you run a `Select` right after executing your `insert()` ?

Comment: @jstreet it shows the data however after restarting the app there is no data.

Comment: Are you running it from the debugger? Try to run your executable from outside VS and the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the quotes around your parameters that are giving you grief. Try the code below and see if it works any better.

```
try {
    Connection.Open();
    string query = "Insert into checkouts(cnic,medicine,next_trip) VALUES(@c,@m,@n)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", cnic_box.Text.Replace("-",""));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", med_box.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n",Convert.ToDateTime(date_box.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    Connection.Close();
    return (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Connection.Close();
    return false;
}
```

**Edit**

To explicitly commit the data try replacing your query with this:

```
string query = "BEGIN TRANSACTION Insert into checkouts(cnic,medicine,next_trip) VALUES(@c,@m,@n) COMMIT TRANSACTION";
```

Comment: @BilalAmjad Do you ever use transactions in your code? Could it be that you have closed the transaction and need to open a new one in order to persist the data?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from the VALUES part of the query from the query

```
bool insert()
{
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
        string query = "Insert into checkouts(cnic,medicine,next_trip) VALUES(@c, @m, @n)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", cnic_box.Text.Replace("-",""));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", med_box.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n",Convert.ToDateTime(date_box.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Connection.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```